# Python: sort a list of list based on a list in it

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list

```
list1 = [[a,   e,   o,   i,   u], 
     [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0], 
     [5.1, 4.7, 2.5, 3.2, 1.1]]
```

I want to sort this list based on the 2nd list. i.e. the middle one.
The result should be as follows

```
sorted_list1 = [[o,   e,   a,   u,   i],
            [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
            [2.5, 4.7, 5.1, 1.1, 3.2]
```

Please mention the supporting import modules as well if required.

Note: I have equal number of elements in each list.

Comment: `zip(*sorted(zip(*list1), key=lambda c: c[1]))` should do this (transpose, sort on middle column, transpose again). You may need to add `list()` in Python 3, or wrap in `[list(r) for r in ...]` to output a list of lists again.

Comment: Thanks. This answer works. Is python able to sort only based on columns?

Comment: sorting applies to a *single sequence*. You have 3 sequences, so I combined them into one sequence containing tuples of 3 values each, then reverse the process after sorting.

Comment: In Python 3.6 you can also do `[*map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(*list1), key=lambda c: c[1])))]` if you _really_ need a list of lists instead of a list of tuples.